# Java Springboot: Having trouble loading the java keystore file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a backend application that utilizes a java keystore file, which contains imports of various certificate files I need to establish SSL connections to call upon spotify api. I have my keystore.jks file located under path "src/main/resources/config/keystore.jks" (since "src/main/resources" by default the root resource directory java springboot uses to locate all resource files during compilation process). I checked that after compiling my app, the keystore.jks file is located under target directory, which it does("target/classes/config/keystore.jks"). However, when I launch my spring-boot app it's complaining "unable to create a key store: Could not load store from 'classpath:/config/keystore.jks". I don't know how to go about resolving this. I already made sure my spelling of keystore file is correct in application.properties file and made sure to get a new build before running my spring-boot app. I also listed contents of jar file and made sure it includes keystore.jks file. Much help would be appreciated.

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>play_recommend_backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.example.play_app_backend.MyApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version> <!-- Use the latest version available -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.11</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version here -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

application.properties file:

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:/config/keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=Pp11142001!
server.port=8090
server.ssl.enabled=true
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

Here is the error output I get when I try to run spring-boot app:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-07-30T16:19:20.588-05:00 ERROR 42493 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:602) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.example.play_app_backend.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load store: Unable to create key store: Could not load store from 'classpath:/config/keystore.jks'
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.configureSslStoreProvider(SslConnectorCustomizer.java:124) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.configureSsl(SslConnectorCustomizer.java:93) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.customize(SslConnectorCustomizer.java:59) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.customizeSsl(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:367) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.customizeConnector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:344) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:203) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create key store: Could not load store from 'classpath:/config/keystore.jks'
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.jks.JksSslStoreBundle.createKeyStore(JksSslStoreBundle.java:89) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.jks.JksSslStoreBundle.getKeyStore(JksSslStoreBundle.java:58) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.configureSslStoreProvider(SslConnectorCustomizer.java:116) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load store from 'classpath:/config/keystore.jks'
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.jks.JksSslStoreBundle.loadKeyStore(JksSslStoreBundle.java:118) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.jks.JksSslStoreBundle.createKeyStore(JksSslStoreBundle.java:84) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [/config/keystore.jks] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getURL(ResourceUtils.java:137) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.jks.JksSslStoreBundle.loadKeyStore(JksSslStoreBundle.java:112) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    ... 18 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Does it work without the leading slash in `claspath:/config/...`?

Comment: Do you mean have it like “classpath:config/…”?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the leading slash `/` in the line `server.ssl.key-store=classpath:/config/keystore.jks` in your `application.properties` file.